# Match File Names with Preceding Zeros

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to match exactly match one file in the Printer Spooler folder with RegEx. Basically what I'm going for is match the one file called *[filename].SPL in %windir%\spool\PRINTERS using Python. I thought using a dynamically generated RegEx along the lines of: [matching none or many-zeros] + [filename].SPL

Tried a few Regular Expressions, but always had the issue that the linebreak of the previous file matches as well at regex101.com

File format:

```
02980.SPL
20980.SPL
00011.SPL
00001.SPL
```

Expressions I came up with:

```
[\r\n][^1-9]+1.SPL
[^1-9].*1.SPL
```

Comment: Do you want to say you have a multiline string to handle? Are they not standalone strings?

Comment: If you want to match `00001.SPL`, why use regex?

Comment: It's a list of file names, so probably a string list.

Comment: Well I hoped I could dynamically create the RegEx using [^1-9].*   + [filename].SPL

Comment: Is it always the same filename that you want to match?

Comment: Like `r'^0*{}\.SPL$'.format(filename)`?

Comment: Basically, yes. But your RegEx doesn't state a filename variable for the formatting function.

Comment: @schlumpfpirat What do you mean? Regex can never state any filename variables. `.format()` is used to insert a variable into the string literal where the `{}` is. If you could show the exact test data (in code) with expected results, it would be very helpful.

Comment: I'm aware. Let's assume filename is '1', then ^0*1\.SPL$ doesn't match anything on regex101.com

Comment: Do you mean like https://regex101.com/r/BZb03g/1

Comment: Can you please clarify the constraints of your problem? Do you have a list of names, as in `["20980.SPL", "00011.SPL"]`, or a multiline string, as in "20980.SPL\n00011.SPL"`? Are your filenames numeric, i.e. 1 or 2980, or non-numeric?

Comment: Exactly, thanks Wiktor & Fourth Bird! Even tho I'm kinda confused it doesn't match anything here https://regex101.com/r/UNFRE2/1#

Comment: It matches - https://regex101.com/r/GB2iLn/2 - you did not enable the right flags

Comment: @schlumpfpirat The solutions use multi-line matching, which you can also set as a flag in Python.

Comment: RegEx is so confusing comparingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
r'^0*{}\.SPL$'.format(filename)
```

See the [regex demo online](https://regex101.com/r/GB2iLn/2).

If `filename` is `1`, the pattern will look like `^0*1\.SPL$` and will match:

- `^` - start of string
- `0*` - zero or more `0` chars
- `1\.SPL` - `1.SPL` substring
- `$` - end of string.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/QQsx20):

```
import re
l = ['02980.SPL','20980.SPL','00011.SPL','00001.SPL']
filename=1
rx = re.compile(r'^0*{}\.SPL$'.format(filename))
print([f for f in l if rx.search(f) ])
# => ['00001.SPL']
```